# How to invoke external apps from my Codename One app

Tags: facebook, social-networking, codenameone

I have developed an app for organizing and grouping of hashtags. One functionality I want to add to this app is the following: The user can copy his/hers tags and then should be able to switch to the desired social media app (in fact app or web page). Starting a web page is not a problem but how can I switch to another app (twitter, tumblr, youtube, facebook, atc. etc.) from my own app? I couldn't find any solution for that. Please help!

The complete list of apps I want to start is: Facebook, GooglePlus, Instagram, LinkedIn, Pinterest, Tumblr, Twitter, Vine, Vk, Youtube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `Display.execute` to launch Android/iOS apps implicitly e.g. [this site](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook) lists the URL schemes for various apps including facebook.

On iOS you can also check if an app is already installed using the `Display.canExecute(String)` [API](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/can-execute.html).

For Android I couldn't find a conclusive list of URL's like that but generally googling "intent URI" with your desired network should provide you with the answer.